# while (scanf()==1) doesn't work - what is my mistake?

Tags: c, scanf

Below are two versions of the same program. The first one works, the second doesn't. With `while (scanf()==1)` I wanted to check the scanf. Please, explain what is my mistake (please, in simple terms - I am a beginner :) )

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void)
{
    char string_to_cap[90];
    int i, n;

    // get line of text
    printf ("Please, enter a word: ");
    scanf  ("%89s", string_to_cap);

    if (string_to_cap != NULL) // if s is not NULL than go ahead and execute the code below

    {
        // capitalize text
        for (i = 0, n = strlen(string_to_cap); i < n; i++)
        {
            printf("%c", toupper(string_to_cap[i]));
        }
    }
    printf ("\n");
}
```

Here is the second one that doesn't work:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void)
{
    char string_to_cap[90];
    int i, n;

    // get line of text
    printf ("Please, enter a word: ");

    while (scanf  ("%89s", string_to_cap) == 1);

    {
        // capitalize text
        for (i = 0, n = strlen(string_to_cap); i < n; i++)
        {
            printf("%c", toupper(string_to_cap[i]));
        }
    }
    printf ("\n");
}
```

Comment: maybe remove the semicolon after the `while (scanf() ==1)` ? ;-)

Comment: in your first example: string_to_cap is never (!) NULL

Comment: Remove your semicolon after while. Your condition will never be false with this codding approach.

Comment: How can `string_to_cap` be `NULL` in any case ?

Comment: while loop is having semicolon if that is your requirement then simply enter ctrl+z after your input. then it will work.

Comment: in the first example code, the 'if' statement will always be true.   In the second statement, the 'while' statement will only execute one loop because the input will stop at the first white space and never get beyond that point

Comment: Note: Use `toupper((unsigned char) string_to_cap[i])` to cope when `string_to_cap[i] < 0`.

Comment: I would be grateful for explanation on this NULL issue. I do not understand it. I thought that it reflects the fact that the user might not enter any word.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (scanf  ("%89s", string_to_cap) == 1);
                                           ^
```

Notice the error

This actually means that `while` loop has only one statement, that is `;`

And the blocks after that

```
{
    // capitalize text
    for (i = 0, n = strlen(string_to_cap); i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%c", toupper(string_to_cap[i]));
    }
}
```

are never executed.

Comment: Thank you everyone! I hope to avoid such mistakes in future.

Comment: I have removed the column (indeed, funny mistake), but now the program doesn't even compile. I get the error message: `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
      start in crt1.10.6.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status`

Comment: also, wouldn't my while statement mean an endless loop, that, if at all solves the task, will not exit after the successful output? should i change it for if statement? though still I have to solve the above issue first.

Comment: @Ducol removed the column? And Yes, you need to change to `if` statement.